# How to define minLength of input field but only to calculate inserted digits without blank spaces in GWT?

Tags: extjs, gwt, gxt

I am developing a GWT app where I have input field for phone number. I have set min length of 5 numbers but in my regex blanks spaces are allowed. But now if user enters for exammple:

`1 1 1 1`

Then validation is successfulc(but shouldn't be because I have only 4 numbers). So how I could change method minLength in GWT to not calculate blank spaces. This is my input field:

```
 organizationPhoneNumber.setMinLength(5);
```

Where organizationPhoneNumber is `TextField` of `com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form;` and minLength is method from that class too.

Could anyone helps me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a custom validator for this - it is just an interface, and you can return an error message if it doesn't match:

```
field.setValidator(new Validator() {
    @Override
    public String validate(Field<?> field, String value) {
        //modify the value to remove spaces, then perform a 
        //length check - if valid, return null, if invalid, 
        //return a helpful error for the user to see
    }
});
```